# Saving ARSCNView snapshot in didUpdateFrame method causes camera to freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, github, arkit

I am creating video in ARKit during session. When I press record button, camera freezes. I have written code in didUpdateFrame delegate that causes the problem. There I save scene.snapshot in an array. Also when i create video from these images, app crashes with following message in debugger: 
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

```
    -(void)session:(ARSession *)session didUpdateFrame:(ARFrame *)frame
    {
     if (_recordButton.state  == UIControlStateSelected)
     {
      currentState = Recording;
     [self saveImage];
    }
    else if (previousState == Recording)
    {
    NSLog(@"Stop recording");
    currentState = NotRecording;
    recordTime = NULL;
    self.nextButton.enabled=YES;
   }
//update recording state per frame update
previousState = currentState;
```

}

```
    -(void)saveImage 
    {
      UIImage *image = self.sceneView.snapshot;
      [self.bufferArray addObject:image];
      image = nil;
   }
```

Comment: Pause the debugger inside `didUpdateFrame` and check the stack trace — there's a good chance you're inside the view's rendering loop there, so if you kick off a snapshot you could be kicking off another render, which would call into your `didUpdateFrame` again, and so on until you crash due to infinite recursion. The simplest solution is probably to dispatch-async the snapshot onto the main queue.

Comment: i have checked dispatch-async also but nothing happened.

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
    UIImage *image = self.sceneView.snapshot;
    NSData *compressImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.02);
    UIImage *compessImage = [UIImage imageWithData: compressImageData];
    [self.bufferArray addObject:compessImage];
    compessImage  = nil;
    image = nil;
    });

Answer (score 2):

Do not use ARSCNView.snapshot with implementing ARSessionDelegate.didUpdateFrame. I had same issue and solution was do not implement ARSessionDelegate.didUpdateFrame. I have used CADisplayLink with ARSCNView.snapshot and it works well.
I also tried to use ARFrame.capturedImage, but it has not contain AR objects at all. ARSCNView.snapshot contains them.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to contain AR objects using ARFrame.capturedImage? I'm having that issue.

Comment: No, At this moment Im forgot ARKit like nightmare 8)